# Is it practical to use separate MOSFETs for PWM and direction control?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

I have an idea for a design which I'm curious to get some feedback on. Without worrying about support circuitry, consider the following MOSFET h-bridge:

[image: h-bridge diagram]

The idea is that Q1 is a high-speed, high-efficiency device such as an [IRF6](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/IRF6665TR1PBF/IRF6665TR1PBFCT-ND/1189873), while the remaining devices can be cheaper FETs, for example, a pair of [FDS8984](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/FDS8984/FDS8984CT-ND/1245074)s.

My questions about this concept have to do with the behaviour and properties of MOSFETs:

- What are the consequences for power consumption and heat? My understanding is that most of the losses in a MOSFET occur during switching. If Q2 and Q5 are continuously conducting, does that mean that the losses mostly occur in Q1, or are the others effectively "switching" too, when the upstream supply is being switched by Q1?
- Similarly, what are the consequences for the timing attributes of the devices? Will the rise and fall times be just that of Q1, or is it the max of Q1, Q2, and Q5, or worse, some sum of them?

The specific application being considered is a class D amplifier, but I'm looking to understand these things better generally, as the principles apply to power supplies, motor controllers, etc.

Thanks!

---

Edit to add: The reason this design (if it works) would be particularly excellent for an amplifier is that the PWM for an amp must be 200kHz to 1MHz to achieve accurate sound reproduction, but the direction will only need to be capable of changing as fast as the fastest sampling rate (48kHz). A full-bridge design also enables building an amp with a single power supply.

This design is a way to sidestep the usual objection to full-bridge amplifiers, which is that it takes twice as many of the expensive, audio-grade FETs.

Comment: It sounds like quite a good idea. The only thing I can imagine is that it might just blip a little during a zero crossing. I guess you have to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such circuits may be usable for motor control, but I really wouldn't recommend one for audio applications.  A typical PWM will behave most linearly when it's near 50% duty cycle; linearity falls off badly at the extremes.  In a class D amplifier, a zero-volt input signal is represented by a 50%-duty-cycle output.  As a consequence the zero-crossing point, which is where the ear is most sensitive to distortion, is where the circuit behaves the most cleanly.  If you try to use an H-bridge simply for direction switching and a separate transistor to modulate the output amplitude, it will be very difficult to achieve any sort of smooth behavior near the crossover point.  This will be especially true if one is driving a reactive load where voltage and current are not in phase.  The behavior of a class D amplifier when voltage and current are out of phase will be relatively clean and consistent when the voltage crosses from positive to negative.  By contrast, in a circuit such as you describe, the transition from positive to negative voltage will trigger a sudden change in how the circuit handles the currents that are flowing in the load at the time of the change.  With a practical load, such currents are likely to exist and to be significant.  An abrupt change in them will almost certainly generate audible crossover distortion.

Comment: Can you explain more about PWM linearity? Is this just due to ratios, or is it an inverse square thing, or something else? Is it something which could be compensated for in software?

Comment: PWM waveforms are never switched absolutely cleanly and perfectly.  Even if a processor requests that a PWM waveform switch on for precisely 1% and off for 99%, it's likely that the actual output will take a little while to switch on or off.  If both the "on" and "off" time are long enough that the output is fully on or fully off by the time it's commanded to change, each additional percentage point the wave is on will mean one less percent of "full off" time and one more of "full on" time.  On the other hand, ...

Comment: ...if the output is on for such a short time that the switch never gets a chance to stabilize before it turns back off, increasing the on time by one percentage point will not add a full percentage point of "full on" time, but generally some amount less than that.  A certain amount of software compensation is possible, but the effects one would have to deal with are apt to be dependent upon many factors including temperature and aging.  It's much easier to simply use a design where the PWM output is employed in its more-linear region.

Comment: @mikepurvis: See above two comments.  Also note that if one drives a reactive load with an H-bridge that is PWM'ed quickly between positive and negative with a "75% positive" duty cycle, the load will behave roughly as it would fed a voltage which is 75% of the way from the negative rail to the positive rail (i.e. half the positive maximum, if the rails are balanced).  Modulating just the on/off FET, the percentage duty cycle which is required to maintain that average voltage will vary severely depending upon the exact characteristics of the load.

Answer (score 2):

Several comments:

**1)** The IRF6665 is neither faster nor more efficient than the FDS8984.

**IRF6665 @ Vgs=10 V:**
Rds_on_typ = 53 mohm
Qg_typ = 8.4 nC
Qgd_typ = 2.8 nC

**FDS8984 @ Vgs=4.5 V:**
Rds_on_typ = 24 mohm
Qg_typ < 5 nC
Qgd_typ < 2 nC

The FDS outperforms the IRF in all three parameters, so it will be faster and more efficient. Your IRF is more expensive just because it has a higher voltage rating, and because it can dissipate more power.

**2)** Assuming we had a fast and efficient Q1 and slower and less efficient {Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5}:

**2.1)** It doesn't make any sense for Q1 to have a higher voltage rating than each of {Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5}. Each of them has to stand a reverse voltage equal to the supply voltage. I'll explain more, if you want.

**2.2)** Capacitor losses only happen when, for a capacitor, *its voltage changes*. If you keep Q2 and Q5 always ON, neither of their Cgs or Cgd capacitances will change in voltage (see figure), and therefore, they will *not* incur in switching losses (only ohmic losses, due to Rds_on). Only Cgs and Cgd of Q1 will be changing in voltage and therefore the only switching losses will happen there. So yes, by using that topology, you reduce from 2 to 1 the number of transistors that have switching losses, at any time.

[image: Equivalent circuit]

**2.3)** You do reduce switching losses, but increase the ohmic losses. Talking only about the latter ones, Q2 to Q5 will continue dissipating whatever they were dissipating, and you add a new element, Q1, with a nonzero Rds_on, and therefore new losses. It won't always be the case that you will have a net benefit (it will be for high frequencies).

**2.4)** I've never seen that in digital audio. I'd bet that the small benefit in efficiency (if any) wouldn't compensate the added complexity in control, added price of Q1, and added distortion (Q1 is nonlinear, and you have a discontinuity at your center range that you have to deal with).

**2.5)** The rise and fall times will be those of Q1 (and taking into account that you have the Rds_on of three devices in series, now). Q2 and Q5 will not add rise/fall time, if kept ON.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your thoughts. I should have taken more care in the components I put forward for the example, so that it made more sense. (eg, the IRF6722 would probably be a more realistic choice for the PWM device).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP understands about the switching losses. Actually gate capacitance causes losses twice. Once for having to charge the gate, and again for the slower transition time where the FET is dissipating power. The more current you're driving, the more significant this becomes.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet "I'm pretty sure the OP understands about the switching losses". (?) Well, if he writes "or are the others effectively switching too?", there's something he doesn't understand. I saw I could help, and did it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those things which might just about pay off, but probably not a huge amount. The advantage is not immediately obvious, and may only become clear after a lot of shopping for transistors, and calculations of the benefits.

From the question, it sounds like the only reason for doing this is to save on part cost (which is surprising considering how much audiophiles are usually willing to fork out on equipmemt). Therefore you'll have to be totally sure that the high performance transistor + gate driver, and 4 low performance transistors really are cheaper, and that you couldn't actually make the 4-transistor design cheaper just by shopping harder.

I'd start be carefully defining the performance spec you need. Then actually go through the tedious calculation+shopping loop. Selecting parts for both designs, then simulating them in LTSpice to work out the actual losses, then trying more parts based on the results of the simulations. Was the performance within spec? What if you swap in a cheaper transistor, is it still within spec? etc.

It's tedious work, but the pay off at the end is two fold: 1. having a more optimal (cheaper) design and 2. knowing you proved wrong all the nay sayers.

Comment: The alternative isn't even necessarily four high-performance transistors—another option would be 2+2. Most low-cost designs use 1+1 in a half-bridge, but then you need a split supply, which has its own costs.

Comment: It's true that audiophile stuff is often pricey. The idea of this project is to figure out how to build an all-digital DIY Class D amp that sounds great and is economical (so, no $40 FPGAs to do DSP stuff).

Comment: @mikepurvis No DSP? How will you do the UPWM-to-NPWM and the noise shaping?

Comment: An XMOS device, either the L1 or L2. There are monolithic class D controller ICs, but they mostly start with an analog input, whereas I'd like to start with an SPDIF signal, do the crossover filtering digitally, etc. Part of the reason to be cost-sensitive on this aspect of the design is that I'm picturing it would be scalable to a system of 5 or even 7 powered speakers.